# Power BI DAX:Matrix with division of two columns where data summarized by category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to get a % of two columns in Power BI matrix.

So I want to divide Total CCI Amount / Total Revenue and multiply by 100%. I want to have a new column in the matrix that does this calculation called CCI %.

It seems simple, but I am having trouble despite searching and trying a lot. I am very beginner in PowerBI.

Can anyone help with this?

I think the issue is in how my dataset is designed, but I cannot change it as this is just a sample from actual report that comes in this format[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create two appropriate measures:

```
Total CCI Amount = SUM ( Tab[Actuals], Tab[Category] = "Total CCI Amount" )
Total Revenue    = SUM ( Tab[Actuals], Tab[Category] = "Revenue" )
```

Then just add third measure:

```
CCI% = DIVIDE ( [Total CCI Amount], [Total Revenue] )
```